# If (textBox1.Text == ("admin")) + (textBox2.Text == ("admin)) in C#

Tags: c#

I want to use one command which will contain two "textboxes.Text" in one "If". I mean when I did this command :

`If (textBox1.Text == ("admin")) + (textBox2.Text == ("admin))` or this  `If (textBox1.Text == ("admin) , textBox2.Text == admin))`  it isn't right.

The main code is:

```
  private void Label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (textBox2.Text == ("admin")) + (textBox1.Text == ("admin"))
         {
             Label.Text = "right";
         }
         else
         {
             Label.Text = "wrong";
             errorProvider1.SetError(errorprovider, "Wrong Username or Password");
         }
```

Namely the thing I wanted to do is if one of two textboxes is wrong the label will show that the password or the username is wrong ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for an `if` statement is:

```
if (condition) body
```

Your current code is:

```
if (textBox2.Text == ("admin")) + (textBox1.Text == ("admin"))
```

... which is treating `textBox2.Text == ("admin")` as the condition, and then trying to use `+ (textBox1.Text == ("admin"))` as the body, which isn't valid. The problems are:

- You're closing the condition too early
- You're using the wrong operator for "and"

Additionally, you're putting parentheses around string literals for no obvious reason, reducing readability. So what you really want is:

```
if (textBox2.Text == "admin" && textBox1.Text == "admin")
```

Note that other answers have suggested using `||` instead of `&&` - that would be an OR condition, which would show a result of "Right" if *either* of the textboxes had a value of `admin`. I suspect that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (textBox1.Text == "admin" && textBox2.Text == "admin")
    Label.Text = "right";
else
    Label.Text = "wrong";
```

`&&` is the boolean AND operator.  `||` is the boolean OR operator.

Answer (score 1):

Check the MSDN page on [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You're looking for `||` (conditional or) or `&&` (conditional and).

The other name for conditional operators is "short-circuiting", because they only evaluate the second condition if they need to.   In other words, with `a && b`, when `a` is false, the entire expression must be false, so the expression b is not evaluated.  This is significant when `b` has side effects, or when `a` implies whether it is safe to evaluate `b`.  Examples:

```
if (MethodA() && MethodB()) //...
```

Here, MethodB is called only when MethodA returns true.

```
if (o != null && o.Equals(p)) //...
```

This is safe (and common), because it saves us from the `NullReferenceException` when o is null.

You can also use the non-short-circuiting versions of these operators (`|` and `&`) with boolean expressions, but this is so rare that most programmers will read it, at first glance, as a mistake; it's better to be more explicit if you want the code always to evaluate both expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(textBox2.Text == "admin" && textBox1.Text == "admin")
{
    //both admin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a simple or? Use the double vertical pipe ||

```
private void Label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (textBox2.Text == ("admin") || textBox1.Text == ("admin"))
        {
            Label.Text = "right";
        }
        else
        {
            Label.Text = "wrong";
            errorProvider1.SetError(errorprovider, "Wrong Username or Password");
        }
}
```

Comment: Check Jon Skeet's answer: you didn't catch the incorrect parentheses in the sample code (and neither did I).

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((textBox2.Text == "admin") || (textBox1.Text == "admin"))
        {
            Label.Text = "right";
        }
        else
        {
            Label.Text = "wrong";
            errorProvider1.SetError(errorprovider, "Wrong Username or Password");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "and" operator which is "&&" in C#.

```
if (textBox1.Text == ("admin")) && (textBox2.Text == ("admin))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is incorrect. The correct syntax is

```
if (A && B) { ... }
```

So in your case it should be

```
if(textBox1.Text.Equals("admin") && textBox2.Text.Equals("admin")) { ... }
```

You may want to read up a bit on Boolean algebra if this logic is confusing you.

Note the other changes we've all suggested as well - you had extra brackets and should be using `Equals()` for string comparison as well.